# Array element-based joining

Tags: arrays, node.js, underscore.js

I use http://underscorejs.org/.

The question is the following, I have a number of arrays whose elements are arrays,
for example

```
array1 = [[1,2],[1,3],[4,5]]
array2 = [[2],[4,6]]
```

The question is I want to join the arrays by elements, like following

```
array3 = array1 join array2
array3 = [[1,2],[1,3,4,6],[4,5]]
```

Is there are any elegant way for element-based joining with underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(_.map(_.zip(array1, array2), function(item) {
    return _.uniq(_.flatten(_.compact(item), true));
}));
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3, 4, 6 ], [ 4, 5 ] ]
```

**Step by step Explanation:**

```
console.log(_.zip(array1, array2));
/*[ [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2 ] ],
    [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 4, 6 ] ],
    [ [ 4, 5 ], undefined ] ]*/
```

We apply `_.uniq(_.flatten(_.compact(item), true))` on each and every item in the list.

1. First `_.compact` will be applied on the items. This is important because, we have to get rid of `undefined` in the last element.
2. Then we `_.flatten` the arrays, so that `[ 1, 2 ], [ 2 ]`, will become `[ 1, 2, 2 ]`
3. Then we take only the unique elements. So the output becomes `[1, 2]`

**Edit:** Actually, if you like one-liners, you can do

```
_.map(_.zip(array1, array2), _.compose(_.uniq, _.flatten, _.compact));
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3, 4, 6 ], [ 4, 5 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `join = zipWith concat` :-)

With underscore, you'd write

```
array3 = _.map(_.zip(array1, array2), function(els) {
    return _.flatten(_.compact(els), true)
    // or just: els[0].concat(els[1] || []);
});
```

Comment: You can make this a bit shorter with `partial`: use `_.partial(_.flatten, _, true)` as the iterator.

Comment: @AaronDufour: I know, but I think that might have been too confusing | Edit: and it wouldn't work :-(